# Keep original lombok builder setter and overload

Tags: java, lombok

I'm making a Builder using lombok but have noticed that if I overload a setter, it stops generating the original.

In example below, there's no setter for `NamedIdentity player` anymore. In my case, I want both the original and the overload. I don't see any documentation that forces the original so I see only two options:

- Manually add the missing setter myself
- Name the second setter differently

```
public class Activity {

    @Builder()
    public Activity(NamedIdentity player) {}


    public static class ActivityBuilder {

        public ActivityBuilder player(UUID uuid, String name) {
            this.player = new NamedIdentity(uuid, name));
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make Lombok ignore existing methods by annotating them with [`@Tolerate`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Tolerate).

Comment: Worth noting that it's experimental. (I know you know that, but some people might reasonably prefer to avoid such features)